# SignalR client method fires multiple times

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-web-api

I'm playing around with SignalR, trying to create a heatmap overlay on a Google map. However, my method is firing multiple times and I can't figure out why.

The data returned from SQL is formatted into JSON, so I can plot it onto the overlay using this plugin - http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/

I've been following the web api demo found at http://techbrij.com/database-change-notifications-asp-net-signalr-sqldependency but without luck. My code is below:

View (snipped to show relevant code)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var heatmap;
    var testData;

    $(function () {

        // Proxy created on the fly
        var sales = $.connection.productSalesHub;

        // Declare a function on the product sales hub so the server can invoke it
        sales.client.displaySales = function () {
            getSalesData();
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getSalesData();
    });

    function getSalesData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../api/values',
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json'
        })
            .done(function (res) {
            if (res.length > 0) {
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.3333, 16.35);
                // sorry - this demo is a beta
                // there is lots of work todo
                // but I don't have enough time for eg redrawing on dragrelease right now
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 2,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                    disableDefaultUI: false,
                    scrollwheel: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    navigationControl: true,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    scaleControl: true,
                    disableDoubleClickZoom: false
                };

                testData = res;

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("heatmapArea"), myOptions);

                heatmap = new HeatmapOverlay(map, {
                    "radius": 15,
                    "visible": true,
                    "opacity": 60,
                    legend: {
                        position: 'br',
                        title: 'Amount of items sold'
                    }
                });


                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
                    heatmap.setDataSet(testData);
                });
            }
            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                alert("complete");
            });
    }

</script>
```

Values controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    ProductSalesRepository repo = new ProductSalesRepository();


    // GET api/values
    public JObject Get()
    {
        var data = repo.GetProductSalesData();
        return repo.BuildJson(data);
    }


}
```

ProductSalesHub.cs

```
public class ProductSalesHub : Hub
{
    public static void Show()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProductSalesHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displaySales();
    }
}
```

And lastly, my repo

```
public class ProductSalesRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductSalesInfo> GetProductSalesData()
    {
        using (
            var connection =
                new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT top 10 [lat],[lng],[count]
           FROM [dbo].[ProductSales]", connection))
            {
                // Make sure the command object does not already have
                // a notification object associated with it.
                command.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(x => new ProductSalesInfo()
                            {
                                Lat = x.GetString(0),
                                Long = x.GetString(1),
                                Count = x.GetInt32(2)
                            }).ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    public JObject BuildJson(IEnumerable<ProductSalesInfo> data )
    {
        IEnumerable<ProductSalesInfo> productSalesInfos = data as List<ProductSalesInfo> ?? data.ToList();
        int max = (from d in productSalesInfos.ToList() select d.Count).Max();

        JObject o = new JObject(
            new JProperty("max", max),
            new JProperty("data",
                          new JArray(from d in productSalesInfos
                                     select new JObject(
                                         new JProperty("lat", d.Lat),
                                         new JProperty("lng", d.Long),
                                         new JProperty("count", d.Count)))));

        return o;
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        ProductSalesHub.Show();
    }
}
```

I've been staring at this for hours now, without figuring out why the ajax call is triggered multiple times.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. I have noticed that this occurs only when there are multiple connection of signalr. Further, if the change event is broadcasted to a signalr group, the issues starts only when there are multiple connections in the same group to which we are transmitting.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem. I was injecting my repository class and had multiple instances of it. Here you are adding the event every time GetProductSalesData() method is called. I would add the event once in the constructor and use the singleton pattern to make sure it is only called once.

Answer (score 0):

Because every client who open the page request the server by signalR and signalR response to all client thats why you see multiple response and request.
use

```
this.Clients.Client(this.Context.ConnectionId).displaySales();
```

instead of

```
 context.Clients.All.displaySales();
```

cheers.